# Jquery DataTable with Ignited-Datatables CodeIgniter issue

Tags: jquery, codeigniter, datatable

Hi friends i am using codeigniter datatables it is working for me but i am facing some problem .

```
table name: employe 

emp_no emp_name emp_type etc.........

100    x        0
101    y        1
102    z        1
103    p        0
```

above table working fine but emp_type column 0 rplace with Not Permanent, 1 replace with  Permanent

database having 0,1 values 0=not permanent emp 1= permanent emp

how to solve this problem

note: don't tell me store the database permanent or not permanent  values
like as

```
<input type="radio" name"emp_typ" value="Permanent">Yes
<input type="radio" name"emp_typ" value="not Permanent">No
```

i am sorting and i need the bellow way

```
  <input type="radio" name"emp_typ" value="1">Yes
    <input type="radio" name"emp_typ" value="0">No
```

Comment: so where's your table rendering code? If was me would have model add extra fields, and tell datatables which column to display and which to filter/sort by

Comment: sorry add_column() can be used to i have implemented edit and delete functionality.i want 0,1 value problem boss

Comment: I know what you want... where's your code?

Comment: $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').dataTable( {
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bServerSide": true,
        "sAjaxSource": "scripts/server_processing.php"
    } );
} );

Comment: did you try my suggestion of adding new fields after you `get` from db and before converting to json?

Answer (score 0):

Create a helper function get_type to change the data

```
function get_type($type)
{
  if($type == 0) return 'Not Permanent';
  if($type == 1) return 'Permanent';
}
```

Then you can use the helper with edit_column to change the data

```
$this->datatables->edit_column('Type', '$1','get_type(emp_type)');
```

Make sure to load the helper before calling get_type in edit_column.